# join,concatenate two dataframe based on reteated column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, concatenation

i have 2 data frames:

df1:

```
date     column1           
2014-03-13   1
2014-03-14   2
```

d2:

```
    date        Id people  value                      
2014-03-13   1      A   -3.0
2014-03-13   1      B   -6.0
2014-03-14   1      A   -3.1
2014-03-14   2      B   -5.0
```

and i want to  get a df3 =

```
     date   Id people  value   column1

2014-03-13   1      A   -3.0      1
2014-03-13   1      B   -6.0      1
2014-03-14   1      A   -3.1      2
2014-03-14   2      B   -5.0      2
```

i try with the function join of pandas but i get some errors  there any way to resolve it

Comment: Is performance important in your solution?

Comment: @jezrael yes thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `merge` if joined column is only `date` in both `DataFrames`:

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left')
```

---

```
df['new'] = df2['date'].map(df2.set_index('date')['column1'])
```

Also check if `dtypes` are same in both `DataFrame`s:

```
print (df1['date'].dtype)
print (df2['date'].dtype)
```

If not, convert column to `datetime`, e.g.:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='date', how='left')
```